# Where can I find the list of all possible sendrawtransaction RPC error codes & messages?

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development, sendrawtransaction

Where can I find the list of all possible `sendrawtransaction` RPC error codes & messages?

Such as this:
`{"code":-22,"message":"TX decode failed. Make sure the tx has at least one input."}`

Answer (score 2):

The code for the `_rawtransaction` RPCs is in [/src/rpc/rawtransaction.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpc/rawtransaction.cpp) including your example of the "TX decode failed" error message.

If you do a `Ctrl-F` or `git grep` in that file for `JSONRPCError` you'll see some of the other error messages but that may not be an exhaustive list.